# Panel in MDI Parent overlapped by child when maximized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mdi

I'm writing a windows application using VS2010 and C# 4.0. I have a MDI Parent form, and I need to have a "settings panel" at the bottom of it. I used a borderless form for this purpose. But now while the application is running, when I maximize a child form it overlaps the settings panel. How can I avoid that? My settings panel should always be visible and never overlapped by anything else.

Comment: You need to set the panel's Dock property so the MDI client window (dark gray) gets smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a `Form` for this. You should be using a simple `Panel`. Follow these simple steps:

1. Set your main form's `IsMdiContainer` to `false`.
2. Add a `Panel` to your main `Form` and dock it to the bottom (or whatever option you prefer, left, right, etc.). This pannel will be your settings panel.
3. Set your main form's `IsMdiContainer` back to `true`.
4. Add all relevant controls to your settings panel which will always be visible.

Steps 3 and 4 can be done in any order.

The reason to first set the `IsMdiContainer` to `false` is to make sure you can dock your `Panel` inside the client space of the `Form` and not to inside client space of the `MdiContainer` control (which is automatically added by the designer when you set `IsMdiContainer` to `true` with it's docking set to `Fill`). If you were to dock it inside the `MdiContainer` the `Panel` would be hidden by any MdiChild you were to open. Note that you can not interact directly with the `MdiContainer` control in the designer.